# Brace spanning multiple lines

Tags: brackets

Good afternoon.

I would like to get this (the picture below) but I don't know how to get it and I don't know a name of that. :)

Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be math environment `cases`: \begin{cases}some text\\ some text \end{cases}.  For this you need package `mathtools`. Also iz possible to obtain with `array`, etc

Comment: Is `some text` to be set as math, roman text, or italic text?  Does the whole construct appear in math mode, or in text mode?

Comment: For braces in more complex situations, see also the documentation of the `empheq` package (which loads `mathtools` anyway).

Comment: Since you question is not very clear this can be some regular text in italic shape which has on the left side curly braces. This can be done by use of `tikz` package with `tikzmark` library.